# Cant find Shared Object on runtime. KRPC

Tags: c++, linux, linker

Im trying to use a library named krpc. It is installed with cmake according to the instructions. https://krpc.github.io/krpc/cpp/client.html#using-the-library

This is the test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <krpc.hpp>
#include <krpc/services/krpc.hpp>

int main() {
  krpc::Client conn = krpc::connect();
  krpc::services::KRPC krpc(&conn);
  std::cout << "Connected to kRPC server version " << krpc.get_status().version() << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -lkrpc -lprotobuf
```

ldd returns: (other libraries is found)

```
ldd a.out
         libkrpc-0.3.7.so => not found
```

The library is installed from ./krpc-cpp-0.3.7
which contains libkrpc.so.0.3.7.

How do I properly install the library? I tried changing the name of the .so. And making softlinks to /ust/lib. And running ldconfig anew afterwards.

Comment: Try run ldconfig after .so is copied to /usr/lib

Comment: Worked great! Thank you! somehow i missed this. Im new at asking questions here. Will I mark the question as solved, or delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Had to copy the .so to /usr/lib, then run ldconfig.

-Thanks to @Xin Huang